# Short URL or long URL for SEO

Tags: seo, short-url

I am implementing cs-cart for a web site. Which one is better for SEO if possible with a reason or reference. Site sells books stamps cds etc.

```
www.domain.com/book/Java.html (or) www.domain.com/book/programming/Java.html
```

or

```
www.domain.com/Java.html
```

Some says short URLs are good. But isnt it good that stating which category the product it is in. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can go for both, via [canonical URL](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)s.  For example, in the `<head>` of both /Java.html and /book/Java.html:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/book/programming/Java.html" />
```

With that, Googlebot (and Yahoo/MS' spiders) will see the current page as a duplicate of the canonical link and ignore it, without the usual demerits that come with dupe content.

Long URLs are good for being descriptive, clear, & searchable, while short URLs are nice for people to send around to friends and whatever social network du jour - chances are you want both.

Maintaining the different URLs & dupes will add some server work though.  If it's too much effort, I'd go with the long form for the users' sake & search-ability.  "java.html" could just be some random page about coffee, it needs context.

Answer (score 1):

What if it fits into two categories? That would be the case where I say that it's better to go with a short URL because you don't want duplicate content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about someone search google with just "book" or "programming book" keyword. In this case book matches the URL

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the right size for the content of the site. For example the word "book" is redundant in a URL of a bookshop.