# Basic Routing in PHP Application

Tags: php, url, routes, url-routing

I am writing a PHP application. I want to create a single point for all the requests to my application. Is it the best way to have routing logic in **index.php** file & based on parameter in URL, use a switch case to include the required files & create the complete page?

Or

Is there any other way to do it efficiently?

Comment: You could do it through objects - which will sort of be a bunch of logical operators (such as a case) anyway, but it will probably be neater and nicer than doing it in procedural code.

Comment: Yes, this is the way. Most of PHP frameworks do routing this way. Read some tutorials about routing in PHP. But SO is not a place to ask such questions - there are multiple correct answers.

Comment: yes its is the way most PHP application works. but you can make it more cleaner by using php URL routing. look at the [Other SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642403/pros-cons-of-using-index-phpq-path-instead-of-index-php-path-when-routing-url)

Answer (score 0):

Are you making use  of an *MVC* like structure?

To me, the `index.php` should *Bootstrap* the script and it usually contains a few lines of code in my applications, nothing more.

Also I believe the most widely-used way of managing routes is via Apache's `mod_rewrite` or the similar approaches in other web servers.

Using a `switch` statement could simply get out of hand for anything more than 10-20 cases. Here is a very simplified version of what I usually do:

The `http://localhost/news/100` will translate to `http://localhost/index.php?module=news&id=100`.

On the `index.php` I have a *Request Handler* which loads a `module` like this:

```
$app->run( $_REQUEST['module'], 
    array(
        'action' => $_REQUEST['action'], 
        'id'     => $_REQUEST['id']
    )
);
```

The `module` has couple of `actions`. The `run` method of `app` looks if any `action` has specified or not; If not, it will fire the `default` action. In this case it will `show` the news with the id of `100`. Something like this will fire the `edit` action:

```
http://localhost/news/edit/100
```

This is just the idea, the bare-bones. You should not try to use the above PHP code in your application as it is not a production level code. I just wanted to briefly explain an alternative way for the `switch` statement approach.